# Get external storage path in android 6.0?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-external-storage

I'm using moto g phone which is marshmallow version I want to get path of my external memory card but I'm only able to access internal memory(after writing some permissions for marshmallow) i have tried many combinations like below for accessing external memory card

```
     sdpath="/storage/sdcard1";
     sdpath="/storage/extSdCard";
     sdpath="/storage/usbcard1";
     sdpath=System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
```

I have accessed internal memory by writing sdpath="/storage/emulated/0"; but not able to access external memory card by above codes how can i access memory card in android marshmallow as i headr that google have changed accessing permissions from android 6.0  thanks in advance for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i access memory card in android marshmallow

Use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, or `getExternalMediaDirs()` on `Context` to get at app-specific locations on [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Or, use [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html), to allow the user to choose a location, which may or may not be on removable storage.